# Server Redundancy

Tags: web-hosting, web, redundancy

I have web hosts at 3 different locations.  I want to create a fail-safe for the websites, so if one host is down, the web sites are still available.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend there's a direct question involved in your post rather than an inferred one.

What you're looking for is some form of "global load balancing", usually gained via either DNS configuration (i.e. site-by-site round-robin or load-probing) or via hardware GSS products ([Clicky for link](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/contnetw/ps4162/index.html)).

Comment: Well if you want to put it technically, yes that is what I want to do, without extra hardware or overheads, can I do it?

Comment: Yes, "usually gained via either DNS configuration (i.e. site-by-site round-robin or load-probing)" - this requires no extra hardware.

Comment: So, How do I go about do this?

Comment: dunno if this will help? - http://tinyurl.com/yc3ar36

another solution is to get a cheap vps and run LVS on it - point all DNS at it, configured correctly it can tell if one of the servers in the cluster is down and stop sending it requests.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a website that generates income (or for a business with income) you could try placing the burden on a site that is globally located and redundant already, like the Amazon cloud. They can spin up new virtual servers to handle more load when necessary.